# Unexpected Spring Boot auth behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I want to secure all endpoint except `/register` and `/activate`, but the following configuration does not permit unauthenticated calls to the excluded endpoints. What's missing/wrong? I compared it to several tutorials and code snippets but I am not able to find the failure. I have to remove the `.anyRequest().authenticated()` part to be able to call one of the two endpoints, but then all other endpoints are also unsecured.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/activate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's an example of a request (e.g. with curl) that fails, and what is the response?